# GeoServer and CentOS. Permissions denied when trying to create a layer

Tags: django, apache, tomcat, geoserver

I have a Django/Python map application. This application uses gdal library to create geotiffs and tiled layers. Everything works absolutely ok - geotiffs are nicely created, folders with tiles are also created. But there is a problem - I can not create a store and publish a layer, because geoserver says, that it does not have permissions to write to my Django folders. The error message looks like so:

> '/var/www/django_project/django_project/layers/tiled/test_layer1/0/0.prj', "[Errno 13] Permission denied:

And multiple similar error messages. When I check permissions to test_layer1 folder, I see that it is 777 and the owner is apache (not apache tomcat, but apache httpd). I guess the whole problem is in the owner - geoserver for some reason is not able to write to these folders (inspite of 777 permisions). But I'm not sure what owner and what permissions I should set, so that both Django application (or perhaps I should say apache) could write to this folder and GeoServer could read and write to it. By the way, GeoServer is running on top of Apache Tomcat.

Comment: Are all the sub-directories also world-read-write?  For example, if '/var/www/django_project' is not world readable, then the fact that a sub-directory has more permissions would not matter.

Comment: I've recently checked it. Child folders in CentOS do not inherit permissions of their parent folder. So, in fact, I solved the problem by setting permissions recursively on the parent folder, each time when a new child folder with data is created. Besides, I created a group www-data, added two users to this group - apache and tomcat, and assigned the parent folder to this group. So, everything is ok.